# CRM Dynamics:To pass arraybuffer to html web ressource

Tags: javascript, html, dynamics-crm, arraybuffer

First of all I am working on CRM Online 8.2

I'm trying to download a file via button, using this code:
first:

```
 xhr.onload = function (e) {
            var arraybuffer = xhr.response;
            var fileArray = new Uint8Array(arraybuffer);
 var file = fileArray.buffer.slice(fileStart, lastBoundary);
```

Then:

```
 if (typeof window.navigator.msSaveBlob !== 'undefined') {

    window.navigator.msSaveBlob(blob, filename);
}
else {
    var blob = new Blob([file],
        {
            type: type
        });
    var URL = window.URL || window.webkitURL;
    var downloadUrl = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
    if (filename) {
        var a = document.createElement("a");
        if (typeof a.download === 'undefined') {
            window.location = downloadUrl;
        }
        else {
            a.href = downloadUrl;
            a.download = filename;
            document.body.appendChild(a);
            a.click();
        }
```

Assuming that "document.createElement" is not supported by Microsoft, I found another solution, that is using an Html page that holds the download.

the file is an arraybuffer, so  I cannot pass it to the function :

```
Xrm.Utility.openWebResource('Shared/Download',customParameters,300,300);
```

Because customParameters cannot only stock strings.

Have you any idea to accomplish that?

At your disposal

Saad

Comment: Where is `blob` coming from?

Comment: it comes from an XMLHttpRequest, the response is an arraybuffer:
var arraybuffer = xhr.response;
            var fileArray = new Uint8Array(arraybuffer);

Comment: I meant where is the file you are downloading coming from?

Comment: it comes from  another server, it is not saved in CRM

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok here is the solution, I found that we can convert arraybuffer to string and vice versa.

```
/**
 * Convert an Uint8Array into a string.
 *
 * @returns {String}
 */
function Decodeuint8arr(uint8array){
    return new TextDecoder("utf-8").decode(uint8array);
}

/**
 * Convert a string into a Uint8Array.
 *
 * @returns {Uint8Array}
 */
function Encodeuint8arr(myString){
    return new TextEncoder("utf-8").encode(myString);
}
```

For information, if the arraybuffer is too long, it wouldn't work.